# Samsung Galaxy MediaRecorder internal Buffering

Tags: android, video-streaming, galaxy

I am noticing that the behavior of the android.media.MediaRecorder is different on the Galaxy than on my other devices (Hero, Nexus, Incredible, etc.)  The Galaxy seems to write MPEG data to file in 1 minutes intervals (approx 1.5 MB chunks), suggesting that it internally buffers its data.  I need the data to come more quickly than once per minute.  Does anyone have any suggestions on controlling this behavior?  The android.media.MediaRecorder API is quite simplistic and doesn't have control buffer sizes or write intervals.